# Find Multiple Dropdown Lists in Gridview populated by individual SqlDatasources

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dropdown

Hi guys so i have 4 dropdownlists that are each assigned to individual SQL datasources and are placed inside of a gridview.. Like follows.

```
<asp:GridView ID="SupplierView" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="SupplierView_OnRowDataBound" OnPageIndexChanging="SupplierView_PageIndexChanging1" OnSorting="SupplierView_Sorting1" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="GridCenter" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" HorizontalAlign="Center" OnRowUpdated="SupplierView_RowUpdated" OnRowUpdating="SupplierView_RowUpdating" ViewStateMode="Enabled"  >
              <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="MaterialNumber" HeaderText="Material Number" SortExpression="MaterialNumber" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="MaterialDecsription" HeaderText="Material Description" SortExpression="MaterialDecsription" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CountryOfOrigin" SortExpression="CountryOfOrigin">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CountryOfOrigin") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="CountryOfOriginDDL" runat="server"  SelectedValue='<%# Bind("CountryOfOrigin") %>' DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2COO" DataTextField="CountryOfOrigin" DataValueField="CountryOfOrigin" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CountryOfOriginDDL_OnSelectedIndexChanged" >
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ECCN" SortExpression="ECCN">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ECCN") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ECCNDDL" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceECCN" DataTextField="ECCN" DataValueField="ECCN" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ECCNDDL_OnSelectedIndexChanged"  ViewStateMode="Enabled" AutoPostBack="True">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ALCode" SortExpression="ALCode">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ALCode") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ALCODEDDL" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceALCODE" DataTextField="ALCode" DataValueField="ALCode" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ALCODEDDL_OnSelectedIndexChanged">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Preference" SortExpression="Preference">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Preference") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="PrefDDL" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcePREF" DataTextField="Preference" DataValueField="Preference" OnSelectedIndexChanged="PrefDDL_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>

              <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
              <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
              <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
              <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
              <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
              <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
              <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
              <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
              <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
              <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />

        </asp:GridView>
                            <p>   <asp:Button ID="Updatebtn" runat="server" Text="Update" />-<asp:Button ID="Savebtn" runat="server" Text="Save"  />-<asp:Button ID="BtnLogOut" runat="server" Text="Log Out" OnClick="BtnLogOut_OnClick" />  </p>
                        </div>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SapMainServerDataPull %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [MaterialNumber], [MaterialDecsription], [CountryOfOrigin], [ECCN], [ALCode], [Preference] FROM [VendorDetailsRecordsForUpdate] WHERE ([VendorID] = @VendorID)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:SessionParameter Name="VendorID" SessionField="VendorId" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>


                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2COO" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SapMainServerDataPull %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [CountryOfOrigin] FROM [VendorDetailsRecordsForUpdate] ORDER BY [CountryOfOrigin]" UpdateCommand="uspSupplierUpdateECCN" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                            <UpdateParameters>
                                <asp:Parameter Name="ECCN" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                                <asp:Parameter Name="VendorId" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                            </UpdateParameters>
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>


        <asp:Label ID="ErrMsgUpdate" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceECCN" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SapMainServerDataPull %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [ECCN] FROM [VendorDetailsRecordsForUpdate] ORDER BY [ECCN]" UpdateCommand="uspSupplierUpdateECCN" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                            <UpdateParameters>
                                <asp:Parameter Name="ECCN" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                            </UpdateParameters>
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceALCODE" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SapMainServerDataPull %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [ALCode] FROM [VendorDetailsRecordsForUpdate] ORDER BY [ALCode]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourcePREF" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SapMainServerDataPull %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Preference] FROM [VendorDetailsRecordsForUpdate] ORDER BY [Preference]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I am new at coding (still in my learning phase) Sorry for probably a simple question.

at the moment the dropdowns are showing the data i need. But after a postback they all reset back to the original value, i have done a bit of research and i believe i need to reference these dropdowns in the code behind.. I dont want to use sql adapter etc as the sqldatasource seems to be working in at least showing the data..

I will also need to update the application on which values the user selects, so how do i get my dropdowns to save to the database after selection?

I have also seen something about binding the gridview outside of the postback on page load.. Sorry guy i suspect this is standard stuff, but again i cant find any real solution to my specific problem.. I see many examples of sqldataadapter and adding values using a list but i dont want to do this as the values may change over time so directly calling them from sqldatasource seems like the logic step.

this is my code behind so far.. Most of it is not working and im stuff on it. So it probably wont make much sense.

```
{
    public partial class Update : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string Eccn { get; set; }
        public string CountryOfOrigin { get; set; }
        public string AlCode { get; set; }
        public string Pref { get; set; }

        public string VendorId;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (Session["VendorId"] != null)
                VendorId = Session["VendorId"].ToString();
            RefreshGrid(VendorId);

            if (Session["VendorId"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
            }

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                BindGrid();
            }
        }
          public void RefreshGrid(string vendorId)
        {
            try
            {
                //get list of records from vendorId 
                BizManager biz = new BizManager();

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                biz.GetMaterialAndDesc(VendorId);

                SupplierView.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
                SupplierView.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrMsg = App.App.HandleError(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), ex,
                    "Application Failed adding products to the list");
            }

        }


        private string ErrMsg
        {
            get { return ErrMsgUpdate.Text; }
            set { ErrMsgUpdate.Text = value; }
        }

        private string ConvertSortDirectionToSql(SortDirection sortDirection)
        {
            string newSortDirection = String.Empty;

            switch (sortDirection)
            {
                case SortDirection.Ascending:
                    newSortDirection = "ASC";
                    break;

                case SortDirection.Descending:
                    newSortDirection = "DESC";
                    break;
            }

            return newSortDirection;
        }

        protected void SupplierView_PageIndexChanging1(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            SupplierView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            SupplierView.DataBind();
        }

        protected void SupplierView_Sorting1(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = SupplierView.DataSource as DataTable;

            if (dataTable != null)
            {
                DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
                dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection);

                SupplierView.DataSource = dataView;
                SupplierView.DataBind();
            }
        }

        private void RefreshData()
        {

        }

        protected void SupplierView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void SupplierView_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void BtnLogOut_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Logout.aspx");
        }

        protected void CountryOfOriginDDL_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        protected void ECCNDDL_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DropDownList ddl = sender as DropDownList;

            foreach (GridViewRow row in SupplierView.Rows)
            {
                Control ctrl = row.FindControl("ECCNDDL") as DropDownList;
                if (ctrl != null)
                {
                    DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList) ctrl;

                    if (ddl.ClientID == ddl1.ClientID)
                    {
                        SqlDataSourceECCN.UpdateParameters["VendorId"].DefaultValue = "0000107898";
                        SqlDataSourceECCN.UpdateParameters["ECCN"].DefaultValue = ddl1.SelectedValue;
                    }
                }
            }

            //Session["VendorId"] = VendorId;

            //SqlDataSourceECCN.UpdateParameters["VendorId"].DefaultValue = Session.ToString();
            //SqlDataSourceECCN.UpdateParameters["ECCN"].DefaultValue = Eccn;


        }

        protected void ALCODEDDL_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        protected void PrefDDL_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        protected void SupplierView_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            {
                DropDownList dropDownLst = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ECCNDDL");

                dropDownLst.DataSource = SqlDataSourceECCN;

                dropDownLst.DataTextField = "ECCN";
                dropDownLst.DataValueField = "ECCN";
                dropDownLst.DataBind();



              }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In webforms I find it easy just to pump around some DataTables for holding the data. So I use a simple method to get data from the database and return a DataTable with the result.
The query can be a select or a stored procedure.

```
public static DataTable LoadDataFromDB(string query)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection))
    {
        try
        {
            adapter.Fill(dt);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Now you can use `LoadDataFromDB` everywhere to simply populate controls with data.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack == false)
    {
        //as a query
        DataTable dt = LoadDataFromDB("select top 10 * from mytable");
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        //or stored procedure
        DropDownList1.DataSource = LoadDataFromDB("mysp 1, 2");
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "columnA";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "columnB";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

UPDATE

That they are in a GridView does not matter. Simply use FindControl.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = e.Row.FindControl("") as DropDownList;

        ddl.DataSource = LoadDataFromDB("select a from b order by c");
        ddl.DataTextField = "username";
        ddl.DataValueField = "fullwidth";
        ddl.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: But my dropdowns are in a gridview, so how do i reference them. as when i click on a selection in the dropdown it cases a postback and the values reset back to the original.

Comment: @FelicityPerry That does not make a difference, see my update.